# RMarkdown not render correctly

Tags: r, r-markdown

I tried to create a RMarkdown file, with the default template by RStudio like below:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

When I clicked `knit`, it only rendered a raw html file like below, as if no css is applied to the html.
How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Actually there's a `css` file styling `Rmd` [default theme](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html).

Comment: This looks like the correct output - what were you expecting to get?

Comment: [Here you go, prettydoc!](https://github.com/yixuan/prettydoc)

Comment: @joshpk I think that the headers should be styled in blue, and the code should be colored like in Rstudio

Comment: Well this is the default theme, so that is working as expected. If you wanted to change styling on headers and code etc. you would need to provide some CSS code to do that. The [R Markdown guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#appearance-and-style) has an introduction on how to go about this.